# Strange issue with non retina display in iphone

Tags: iphone, image

My app was working fine both in simulator and iPhone 4 when i had only "image.png" . When I added "image@2x.png" screen's UI became distorted in actual device,simulator has  no issues. Device is iphone 4 non-retina. 
Do I need to specify anything when @2x images are added?

Comment: When you say "added" Are you talking about just adding the resource? I hope you aren't actually calling the image with the @2x suffix. Normally you just use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image];` it loads the retina or non-retina version depending on the device's capabilities.

Comment: Also, iPhone 4 is Retina.

Comment: haven't heard of iPhone 4 non retina

Comment: Yes I just adding the resource, not calling it.All images loaded from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you're not using a prerelease of Xcode 5, are you? If so, no one here is allowed to help you, and you should march yourself over to the [Apple Developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).

That is strange. You shouldn't need to do anything other than creating the @2x version. Double and triple check that the files look as expected, and that the 2x version is exactly double the resolution in each direction (that is: if the original is 50x50, the 2x must be 100x100).

Next, try doing **Product->Clean**, delete the app from the device and then run it again. Sometimes weird things are solved that way. Also, restarting Xcode can't hurt, I've had that resolve more than a few Really Weird Issues.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had tried all these, but it didn't work before. Now again I repeated your steps. Its working now.